# Real time of device start recording

Tags: android

I use android.media.AudioRecord.

```
/*initialize AudioRecord*/
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
audioRecord.startRecording();
```

When I start audioRecord with method startRecording(), I want to get real time of device start recording. My time is not real...
Please, help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date date = new Date(time);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); // the format of your date
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4")); // give a timezone reference for formating (see comment at the bottom
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: problem in getting correct time of start recording, not in its format

Comment: if you want to change format than you can specify it in `SimpleDateFormat` constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think MediaRecorder Will be the better option for recordind Audio and you can record the real time audio.

```
public class AudioRecordTest extends Activity
{
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
private static String mFileName = null;

private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

private void onRecord(boolean start) {
    if (start) {
        startRecording();
    } else {
        stopRecording();
    }
}

private void onPlay(boolean start) {
    if (start) {
        startPlaying();
    } else {
        stopPlaying();
    }
}

private void startPlaying() {
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
}

private void stopPlaying() {
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
}

private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}

class RecordButton extends Button {
    boolean mStartRecording = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onRecord(mStartRecording);
            if (mStartRecording) {
                setText("Stop recording");
            } else {
                setText("Start recording");
            }
            mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
        }
    };

    public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Start recording");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}

class PlayButton extends Button {
    boolean mStartPlaying = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onPlay(mStartPlaying);
            if (mStartPlaying) {
                setText("Stop playing");
            } else {
                setText("Start playing");
            }
            mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
        }
    };

    public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Start playing");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}

public AudioRecordTest() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
    ll.addView(mRecordButton,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));
    mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
    ll.addView(mPlayButton,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));
    setContentView(ll);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May be, but I want process raw data with params: MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 11025 SamplingRateinHz. How can I get raw data from file?